# Ending up with an empty request body when I send a request which includes image files and json type parameters using postman, nodejs and express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, postman

I am coding a RESTful API for a multiplatform online ticket shop using nodejs and express for a university project. I have created the model of each event:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const eventSchema = new Schema({
    event_name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    event_description: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    event_date: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
    },
    event_coordinates: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    event_ticket_price: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    }, 
    event_images: [{
        type: String
    }]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Event', eventSchema);
```

,

as well as the model of each image:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const imageSchema = new Schema({
    associated_event: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    name: String,
    data: {
        type: Buffer,
        required: true
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Image',  imageSchema);
```

.

In my events controller I have an asynchronous function with the following code :

```
const addEvent = async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    const { name, description, date, coordinates, ticket_price, images } = req.body;
    const files = req.files;

    if (!name || !description || !date || !coordinates || !ticket_price) {
        return res.status(400).json({ 'message': 'Event\'s name, description, date, coordinates and ticket_price' });
    }

    const foundEvent = await Events.findOne({ event_name: name }).exec();
    if (foundEvent) return res.sendStatus(409);

    if(files){
        const imagesArray = await imagesController.storeImages(files, name);
        console.log(imagesArray);
    }

    try {
        await Events.create({
            "event_name": name,
            "event_description": description,
            "event_date": date,
            "event_coordinates": coordinates,
            "event_ticket_price": ticket_price,
           // "event_images": imagesArray
        });

        res.status(201).json({ 'success': `New event ${name} created!` });
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json({ "message": err.message });
    }
}
```

When I am trying to test this in postman documenter with the parameters that you can see in the image below, I am ending up with an empty request body. [image]

I have tried to insert data into postman with different ways such as adding quotation marks in keys , inserting values with and without quotation marks etc. and also change the addEvent function but I am always ending up with an empty request body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express does not automatically parse the request body. You have to install a middleware that does that for you. A very popular library that parses `multipart/form-data` is [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer)

Here is an example of how you would use multer:

```
const express = require('express')
const multer = require('multer')

const form = multer()

const app = express()

// form.none() is used because you are not uploading any files
// just a text based form
app.post('/events', form.none(), function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.body) // it contains the fields
})
```

This will work for you